# Какие должны быть знания чтобы нормально работать с IPC(Inter-Process Communication)?

Tags: c++

Понимать код можно и даже слегка писать свой, но чувствуются провалы в знаниях и непонимания откуда растут ноги. Что нужно для гладкого катания? Какие книги почитать? Я так полагаю что-то из устройства операционной системы и что-то по работе с ним с помощью C++, но не знаю в каких книгах это искать, так как сейчас нет времени на прочтения большого колва из них, хотелось бы точной наводки по этой теме, чтобы уложится в 2-3 книги максимум.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO [очень толково](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html),

а [это попроще](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html),

и [здесь хороший материал](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/toc.html), причем именно об ОС, тогда как две остальные в основном относятся к сети.

Comment: @avp @mikillskegg
Спасибо, а есть ещё по Windows что-то подобное? А то приложение будет кроссплатформенное.

Comment: Если нужно делать что-то кроссплатформенное, то лучше взять какой-нибудь фреймворк. Например, покопаться в Boost и/или Qt.

Comment: Вот ["Самоучитель Игры на WINSOCK"](http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf) знаю.

Comment: Особо ничего сложного, просто отдельный процесс от основного, чтобы если он упадет, то основной работал, а этот отдельный процесс реализует голосовой чат и отправляет некоторую информацию о пользователях в основной процесс.

Comment: Если "основной" процесс сам запускает "дополнительный" и тот *только посылает* данные в "основной", то IMHO достаточно использовать тривиальный `pipe`.

Возможно, самым переносимым решением будет вызов `popen(voicechat, "r")` в отдельном thread "основного" процесса.

Правда, в таком случае возникают уже проблемы переносимости threads :).

Answer (score 2):

К ответу [@avp](/users/232/avp) добавлю очень любимую мною книжку [M.Kerrisk "The Linux Programming Interface"](http://www.wowebook.info/book/the-linux-programming-interface/). Ну и хорошее знание С и С++.